# Are the set of even functions a subset of continuous functions $C(-\infty,+\infty)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

My book says that the above set is closed under scalar multiplication and addition. I can't seem to under why the given set is closed under scalar multiplication.

For instance, if I take an even function
$u=x^2$

Now check for scalar multiplication:
$cu=c(x^2)$ if $c<0$ (like $-x^2$)

Isn't closure under scalar multiplication now fail because $-x^2$ is not an even function?

Comment: By "subset" did you mean "subspace"?

Comment: Also note that not all even functions are continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $f(x)=-x^2$ is an even function because it satisfies the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Even_functions): 
$$f(-x)=-(-x)^2=-x^2=f(x)\quad\text{ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$.}$$
In the same way you can verify that the set of even functions in $C(-\infty,+\infty)$ is closed under scalar multiplication.